# Importing multiple React components into html

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to inject some React code into an HTML document. I am following React's own documentation and feeding their starter code (a simple like button) into the page. Everything was working great. I changed it to use JSX, changed it to a functional component using hooks instead of a class component with state. No problems.

However, whenever I include an `import` call and try to bring in another component, the component breaks on the page and stops displaying, but doesn't throw any kind of error I can see.

How do I develop in a "react-y" way with components and modularity while injecting it into an html page?

Here is the code I'm working with at the moment:

#### HTML document

```
<body>
  <div id="react-root"></div>

  <!-- inject react, reactDOM and JSX engine -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- point to component -->
  <script src="transpiled/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### React Component

```
'use strict';
import {SecondComponent} from './components/SecondComponent';

const e = React.createElement;

const LikeButton = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);

  if (liked) return 'You liked this functional component.'

  const handleLikeClick = () => {
    setLiked(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLikeClick}>new like button with jsx</button>
      {liked && <SecondComponent/>}
    </div>
  )
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#react-root');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Like I said, any sort of import statement seems to be where it breaks. Can't find resources online about it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're trying to use a regular `import` statement inside a regular JS script file (`app.js`)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Have you tried with `import React from "react"` ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: After a bit of research importing modules between several `<script>` tags is now possible.

This can be achieved adding the Babel Plugin attribute `data-plugins` and setting the value to `"transform-es2015-modules-umd"` which will enable  the [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) pattern.

You'll also need to set `type="text/babel"` on each `<script>` tag.

This will allow you to use the `import` statements directly inside each file. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>React</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel" src="./Header.js"></script>
  <script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel" src="./App.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Working Gist Example](https://gist.github.com/jmmarco/3e7c4621d4ffc9d5bcf0c1e94a609dbf)